# PHP Classes and Curl

Tags: php, oop, curl

To my smartest friends, I googled and tried everything. I am sure that this is just the late night not letting me see/understand the problem. I should mention that I am still in the process of switching to OOP from functional, and I this is my first time I was able to have curl enabled. :( So, feel free to critique any bad practices also..

```
<?php
class urlValidation
{
    public $content;
    public $validUrl;
    public function __construct($validUrl)
    {
        $this->content = $content;
        $this->validUrl = $validUrl;
        $this->getContents();
    }
    public function getContents()
    {
        $this->curlHandler = curl_init($this->validUrl);
        curl_setopt($this->curlHandler, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
        curl_setopt(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false); //changing false to true is the answer!
        $this->content = curl_exec($this->curlHandler);
        curl_close($this->curlHandler);
    }
}
?>
```

called from

```
$suggestUrl = 'http://www.google.com';
$validate = new urlValidation($suggestedUrl);
```

For all of the best of me, I cannot figure out why $this->content prints to the screen without being called. I just simply want that returned HTML to be stored in a variable and not returned/printed/appended to the document.

Comment: Show us how did you initialize your class and call its methods

Comment: Could you please specify what means "prints to screen without being called" - what does it print? As well as where have you instantiated the new object of that class.   
Also, you're setting `$this->content=$content` in the constructor, which doesn't make a lot of sense - where does `$content` come from? And lastly, it's a good practice to stick to conventions, so why not start a class's name with a capital letter.

Comment: @havelock I mean like reads the file's contents and appends it to the dom... it's as if an echo $this->content is happening but its NOT!

Comment: lol sorry for the pure code rage @havelock. As for your OOP critique, I'm not sure why the $this->content = $content is in the constructor. Those freaking mounds of books and tutorials always do it lol. I thought it was a local inheritance and scope thing, but maybe not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP documentation explains it all ;)

> [`curl_exec`](https://www.php.net/curl_exec) returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, if the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option is set, it will return the result on success, FALSE on failure.

So before `$this->content = curl_exec($this->curlHandler);` you need to add this

```
curl_setopt($this->curlHandler, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Comment: It still returns and prints the html to the second page without being called. :/ lol All I want is the returned html saved into a variable.

Comment: @JaredDrake `All I want is the returned html saved into a variable.`  `$this->content = file_get_contents('http://google.com');` will result the same?

Comment: @JaredDrake sorry, my bad, I forgot to add `$this->curlHandler` as first parameter for `curl_setopt`, and option should be `true`. See edited answer.

Comment: @Alexander Larikov I already adjusted that in for you when you gave me the original answer and it didn't work :/

Comment: @JaredDrake I see, but try this code `curl_setopt($this->curlHandler, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);` On my local it works

Comment: @Alexander Larikov wait a minute... You're my freaking hero... Changing that to true did exactly what I wanted. GOD bless you my friend. Thank you so much. :)